# Changing django admin's change_list.html

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-admin

I wanted to customize the django admin and therefore I copy pasted change_list.html from django admin to my project under `templates/admin/section4/section4/change_list.html`

Now I have view and I have written another template : `total_review_count.html` where I have extended `change_list.html`

In view: `change_list_template = 'admin/section4/section4/total_review_count.html'`

Code :

```
{% extends "admin/change_list.html" %}
{% load i18n admin_urls %}
{% block result_list %}
<footer style="color:blue;"> <p >The total review upto date: {{ total_review_upto_date}}<br> 
</p>
<p>The total review to be updated: {{ total_review_tobe_updated}}<br></p>
<p>Total review to be added : {{ total_review_tobe_added }}</p>
</footer>

{% endblock %}
```

But doing this I override all the other previous stuff i.e the model list that django admin provides by default  and only getting the one in this template. Is this the correct way of overriding `change_list.html`? How do I get previous stuff ?

Answer (score 2):

use `{{block.super}}` inside your custom page block

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a directory into your projects path like so: *myproject/templates/admin* (if this is your specified template setting in the DIRS template options within `settings.py`) and create a new file called `change_list.html` in this directory. Django will then use this instead of the default one.

Furthermore you can then use this new `change_list.html` template to expand on.

For further reference on overriding & replacing default admin & registration templates also see: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/ -> search for "Overriding admin templates"

Comment: This is what I did. But I want the previous content also, the one the default one provides.

Comment: Your view should link to total_review_count.html. If so, you need to change the url link of changes_list.html within the {% extends XYZ.html %}. Right now the browser won‘t load the previous content because it is linked wrongly taken your mentioned path. Add /section4/section4 to the extends tag accordingly and remove the url assignment in your view

Comment: I didn't not understand that you are saying **Your view should link to total_review_count.html.** and again you are saying **remove the url assignment in your view**

Comment: I wanted to get the model fields that django admin provides and also the customized one in the above html file.